# boolean variable values in PHP to javascript implementation

Tags: php, javascript, boolean-expression

I've run into an odd issue in a PHP script that I'm writing-- I'm sure there's an easy answer but I'm not seeing it.

I'm pulling some vars from a DB using PHP, then passing those values into a Javascript that is getting built dynamically in PHP. Something like this:

```
$myvar = (bool) $db_return->myvar;

$js = "<script type=text/javascript>
        var myvar = " . $myvar . ";
        var myurl = 'http://someserver.com/ajaxpage.php?urlvar=myvar';
       </script>";
```

The problem is that if the boolean value in the DB for "myvar" is `false`, then the instance of myvar in the $js is null, not `false`, and this is breaking the script.

Is there a way to properly pass the value `false` into the myvar variable?

Thanks!

Comment: IMO this question is NOT a duplicate of the question it is linked to. This question is way more specific. Thankfully it had already been answered usefully, before being locked.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

use `json_encode()`. It'll convert from native PHP types to native Javascript types:

```
var myvar = <?php echo json_encode($my_var); ?>;
```

and will also take care of any escaping necessary to turn that into valid javascript.

Comment: very clever solution Marc, and it works well! Thanks. I should also point out that the issue turns out to have been in casting it to a boolean-- if I cast to int instead, it brings back a 0/1 value and this can be passed to the JS as an int, and evaluated as true/false by JS normally.

Comment: Works! Would be nice to know if this could be done without `json` trick.

Comment: it could, but then you're responsible for producing valid javascript code. remember that json **IS** javascript... so build your own system when you can just use the perfectly good pre-built on?

Comment: THIS IS CORRECT. Since "JSON" means "JavaScript Object Notation" I would stick with this method over var_export which is based on a different notation specific to PHP and not JavaScript.

Comment: I would suggest: `var myvar = <?php echo json_encode($my_var, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>;` because `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` will make it a safe JavaScript value.

Answer (score 6):

This is the simplest solution:

Just use **var_export($myvar)** instead of **$myvar** in $js;

```
$js = "<script type=text/javascript>
        var myvar = " . var_export($myvar) . ";
        var myurl = 'http://someserver.com/ajaxpage.php?urlvar=myvar';
       </script>";
```

Note: [var_export()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) is compatible with PHP 4.2.0+

Answer (score 3):

```
$js = "<script type=text/javascript>
    var myvar = " . ($myvar ? 'true' : 'false') . ";
    var myurl = 'http://someserver.com/ajaxpage.php?urlvar=myvar';
   </script>";
```

Comment: var_export($myvar)? All you guys forgot **var_export()**... :)